# jQuery UI menubar styling

Tags: jquery-ui

I am working on the jQuery UI menubar available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qVLwT/). I would like the menus to be displayed in the center of the bar and not in the left. How do I do that?
I tried to do it by padding, it works, but its not ideal thing to do as it is not appearing at the center if I use different devices.